# Unable to click on this button using webdriver

Tags: selenium-webdriver

http://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjs_alert

Above is the website, cant click on that "try it", no locator techniques working ?

## Below is the code used

```
driver.get("http://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjs_alert");
driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//button[@onclick='myFunction()']")).click();
```

Answer (score 1):

Your element is in`iFrame` so first you need to switch into `frame` and then have to perform your actions.

Use this :

```
driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(By.id("iframeResult")));

driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//button[@onclick='myFunction()']")).click();
```

Use following code to switchback from the `iframe` and do your actions other then this frame's element:

```
driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
```